# Reduce number of queries in ActiveRecord call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following structure:

- AtomType have many Atoms
- Atoms have many TotalSales (with different start and end dates)
- TotalSales have many PerformanceAnalysis

The method `current_total_sales` on AtomType get the maximum date on total sales among Atoms from the same AtomType, and them get all TotalSales that start on the same date.

```
def current_total_sales
  current_start_date = TotalSales.where(atom_id: atoms.pluck(:id)).maximum(:start_date)
  TotalSales.where(atom_id: atoms.pluck(:id), start_date: current_start_date)
end
```

Can it be more efficient?

The method `red_priorities` on AtomType get all Atoms that have TotalSales that have PerformanceAnalysis with `status_id > 2` and order them by `priority` (a PerformanceAnalysis attribute).

```
def red_priorities
  PerformanceAnalysis.where(total_sales: current_total_sales).
    where("status_id > 2").
    order("priority").map(&:atom)
end
```

Can it also be more efficient?

Thanks!

Comment: is `AtomType` relevant here in query? Because, I don't see you mentioning it in any of the query except the introductory backgrounds of the associations.

Comment: It is, because when I `pluck` the id from `atoms`, that `atoms` belongs to the same AtomType. It's calling a relationship collection from an AtomType instance :)

Comment: Also, from where are you getting `atoms ` object? Is it also a method with a query? If so, can you post that too?

Comment: It's actually (or also) `self.atoms` :)

Comment: What do you mean by `self.atoms`? Is it a method which returns `Atom` objects? Can you post that code as well?

Comment: Actually there is no code.. As I said AtomType has many Atoms. It's just a relationship collections. It returns all atoms that belongs to that instance of AtomType.

Answer (score 0):

I came up extracting the `current_start_date` object to a method and changed the `red_priorities` method to look directly on the Atoms table joining where I need the restriction. That way I avoided the `map(:atom)` at the end of the query (that was not part of the SQL query).

```
def current_start_date
  current_start_date = TotalSales.where(atom_id: atoms.pluck(:id)).maximum(:start_date)
end

def current_total_sales
  TotalSales.where(atom_id: atoms.pluck(:id), start_date: current_start_date)
end

def red_priorities
  Atom.joins(:total_sales => :performance_analysis).
    where("total_sales.start_date = ?", current_start_date).
    where("performance_analyses.status_id > 2").order("performance_analyses.priority")
end
```